# In BCD, what do the elements "displaymessage" and "displaymessageoverride" do?

Tags: bcd, bcdedit

As the question says.

I can't find documentation covering the purpose of `displaymessage` and `displaymessageoverride`.

It looks like BCD entries can have up to 3 names - the description which is what actually appears, a "display message" ..... and then a further "override" of the display message.

What's going on?  When would you use these?

Comment: What are you talking about? BCD entries [have](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/bcd-settings-and-bitlocker) a hex value and a friendly name, that's it. `Displaymessage`/`displaymessageoverride` if any are two types of bcd setting for the Windows Boot Loader. We do [actually know](https://www.geoffchappell.com/notes/windows/boot/bcd/elements.htm) their possible values.. it's just unclear what they toggle (something about bootux probably, but in my quick testing I couldn't spot differences)

Comment: When BCD boot entries are listed for the user, sometimes I've seen the stipulated "description" overridden. For example an entry listed in BCD as "Windows 10 recovery" might just be listed as "Recovery". So I'm trying to understand what's overriding what here, except now I find there are 2 override entries, plus an original description...... Confused? I am!